# SED Insert text after a specific multi-line text field

Tags: sed, centos

I am looking to search for and add a new line of text after a specific multi-line text, in this example i need to add a space and text after "oldText" under "[old-text]" only:

```
[old-text]
oldText

[inserted-new-text]
newTxt

[alsoOld-text]
oldText
```

Here's what I have so far but the syntax is not correct:

```
printf "[old-text]\noldText"|sed '/\[old-text]\noldTex\t/a [inserted-new-text]\nnewTxt'
```

Comment: while not recommended for these sort of tasks, if  you really must use `sed`, the please work your way thru the [Grymoire's Sed Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) . Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed -e '/\[old-text\]/{N;s/oldText/&\n\n[inserted-new-text]\nnewTxt/}' inputFile
```

Use `/<pattern>/` to find the `[old-text]` and then use `N;` to go to the next line and replace.

```
$ printf "[old-text]\noldText" | \
  sed -e '/\[old-text\]/{N;s/oldText/&\n\n[inserted-new-text]\nnewTxt/}'
[old-text]
oldText

[inserted-new-text]
newTxt
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works but can you tell me what the "{ }" brackets are for?

Comment: Not terribly necessary here, but they are used to group commands together. With or without it, you should get same answer.